# Javascript to Update Div Dynamically Not Working on Site

Tags: javascript, magento

I am working on a product page within Magento and I'm trying to get a custom option text field input to update contents of a div dynamically.  The code is working fine in JSFiddle, however, it is not working on the live page.  I need help diagnosing why the code won't work on the page.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cyXq/57/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" id="options_35_text" class="input-text required-entry  product-custom-option length-input" name="options[35]" value="10">
<br />Length: <div id="length" style="display:inline-block;">10<div>
```

JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById('options_35_text'); 
input.onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = input.value;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use js like this :

HTML:

```
<input id="inp"type="text" onkeyup="func()" value="10">
<br />Length: <div id="length" style="display:inline-block;">10<div>
```

JS :

```
function func() {
    var input = document.getElementById('inp'); 
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = input.value;    
}
```

Or you can write like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func() {
    var input = document.getElementById('inp'); 
    document.getElementById('length').innerHTML = input.value;    
}
</script>
<input id="inp"type="text" onkeyup="func()" value="10">
<br />Length: <div id="length" style="display:inline-block;">10<div>
```

In JSFidle you can chose where you want to load your js part (click the gear near "javascript). When I put in "No wrap -in body" the first method works ^^

Comment: The function didn't seem to make a difference.  :-/

Comment: I think I was missing the `()` when calling the function.  It is working now.  Thank you for your help!